# Using azure to find out who is calling a url on app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I’ve got a web api that is hosted on an app service plan with a connected app insights instance

This api is consumed by a web app but it is public facing.

Looking at app insights I can see a vast number of calls being made to an end point that doesn’t exist.

It’s the root of the app. There’s nothing at this root. You have to specify a given endpoint.

I’m now on a hunt to discover who is calling the root. There’s nothing in our client that makes this call.

App insights isn’t very helpful. All IPs are 0.0.0.0.

We go have azure front door.

How can I go about determining who is calling it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the calls are logged as coming from IP 0.0.0.0, is because the call is coming from a load balancer. In your case Azure Front Door.

So you need to look at the logs in Azure Front Door to find out where the calls are coming from.

It may be that the calls are coming from the health check probe on Azure Front Door.

Comment: Wouldn’t that mean it’s unhealthy?